# Как создавать скрипты на beanshell и пользоваться ими?

Tags: java, beanshell

поступило задание реализовать некоторую часть программы используя beanshell скрипты. задание такое: в скрипте содержатся определенные правила для обработки текста. скрипт принимает текст и выдает результат обработки. Я перелопатил мануал на официальном сайте и ничего не понял. Есть где примеры скриптов и того как их исполльзовать из java-кода? или кто, быть может, может объяснить так, учитывая что с java, в общем-то, дружу.

**UPD:**в общем, запилил я такой скрипт:
import java.util.*;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

```
public Boolean getMessageAcceptability(final String from, final String to, final String subject, final String plainText){

    String result = "";
ArrayList<String> regexps = new ArrayList<String>(java.util.Arrays.asList("sdf", "Вышлите", "вышлите"));

    boolean reason = true;
    //System.out.println("message received");
    if (reason){
            for (String regexp: regexps){
                if (reason){
                    Pattern pt = Pattern.compile(".*" + regexp + ".*",  Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE | Pattern.UNICODE_CASE);
                    Matcher mt = pt.matcher(plainText);
                    if (mt.find()){
                        result = result + "DENIED. reason: " + regexp;
                        reason = false;
                    }
                }
            }
    }
    if (reason){
        result = result + "ACCEPTED";
    } else {
    }
    return reason;
}
```

запускаю я его так:

```
try {
             scr = new Interpreter();
            scr.source("/etc/dlp/sample_script.bsh");
            scr.set("from", from);
            scr.set("to", to);
            scr.set("subject", subject);
            scr.set("plainText", plainText);
            Object res = scr.eval("getMessageAcceptability(from, to, subject, plainText)");
            reason = (Boolean) res;
        } catch (Exception e){
            LOG.error("error while interpreting script");
        }
```

и он постоянно выдает мне true, в то время как если я этот код запихну в класс и вызову метод он выдает false когда надо, и когда надо true/

Что я делаю не так?

Comment: [Наслаждайтесь][1].


  [1]: http://www.beanshell.org/examples.html

Comment: а есть ли возможность создавать и менять скрипты непосредственно из кода, потому что, опять же, мне на каждого пользователя нужен свой набор правил(и было высказано пожелание делать каждый набор отдельным скриптом) и любой юзер может захотеть отредактировать свои правила

Comment: В одном из [примеров][1] показывается, как загружать и выполнять BeanShell-скрипты непосредственно из файла на диске, так что да, всё вышеописанное возможно.

  [1]: http://www.beanshell.org/examples/callscript.html

Comment: А ещё есть [eval][1], что упрощает вышеописанную задачу.

  [1]: http://www.beanshell.org/manual/bshmanual.html#eval()

Comment: не очень помогло, но спасибо

Comment: ну вот я написал скрипт, потом вызываю его из кода `scr = new Interpreter().source("/etc/dlp/sample_script.bsh");` и что дальше? как мне обратиться к методам, которые в этом скрипте?

Comment: Вы ведь не читали документацию, не так ли?

    Interpreter i = new Interpreter();
    i.source("script.bsh");
    i.set("param1", 10);
    i.set("param2", 30);
    Object result = i.eval("someMethod(param1, param2)");

Comment: пока что не получается добраться до проверки работы скрипта. как привязать к скрипту библиотеки? или java.util  как минимум будет браться из jre системы?

Comment: попытался использовать скрипт не дожидаясь вашего ответа, вот у меня какая проблема сейчас: `Exception in thread "Thread-9" bsh.Parser$LookaheadSuccess`

Answer (score 1):

BeanShell это надстройка над ява, так что все, что есть в яве отлично используется. Просто в этом "языке" сделан больше упор на скриптование, т.е. именно создание скриптов.